# Make bash terminal cursor flash to the beat of Survivor - "eye of the tiger"

Tags: bash, terminator

I was listening to Survivor - "Eye of the Tiger" and writing some documentation in Vim and noticed that the cursor not flashing to the beat started to annoy me. Can this be fixed?

I'm using `Terminator` and `bash`.

Comment: What a delightfully horrible idea, +1 :).

Comment: What would be hardest I suspect is programmatically determining what the "beat" of the song is.

Comment: You might be able to get it to flash with the primary beat, but *somewhere* within the song there are bound to be speed changes or holds that would mess it all up again.

Comment: @techturtle Not necessarily true. Depends on whether or not Survivor used a metronome while recording. Odds are they did, but there's no way I'm listening to check.

Comment: Gstreamer's `bpmdetect` uses a sliding window / rolling average for beat detection and sends events each time it updates the value, AFAIK. Pretty accurate. Should work. Mostly.

Comment: I need clarification on this question. @StephenMartin, do you want the beats to be just the monotonic "duh, duh, duh, duh, duh" implied in the melody? Or do you want it to be the irregular "DUNT! duh, duh, DUNT! duh, duh DUNT! dun dun duuuuuuuuuh"? Or do you want the pizzicato tympani beats as in "tztztztztztztztz"? Also, we need a way to indicate beat intensity in `Terminator` with variable blink brightness or something if you want the irregular beats.

Comment: While you're at it, I want the cursor color to change appropiate to the lyrics when I'm playing Jimi's `Bold As Love`.

Comment: @allquixotic I see it flashing every half beat for the duna duna duna intro, but staying on for the power chord hits. Then when it hits the the main beat hitting on the regular bpm but again pausing in the on position for the power chords.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the "duna duna duna"? I'm not familiar with that part. Are we thinking of the same song? This isn't some kind of Eye of the Tiger remix from the "numa numa" guy, is it?

Comment: @allquixotic duna duna duna duna duna duna duna duna duna duna duna duna DUN ..DUN. DUN..DUN... DUN. DUN..DUN ... DUN..DUN. DUNNNNNNNN. repeat...

Comment: @r.tanner.f Looks like you're right.  Listening to the song on my iPod and following along at http://www.webmetronome.com/ I came up with a pretty consistent 109 BPM.

Comment: Thanks for the description of the "duna". I understand now. The dunas are small, fast and subtle, like the little flakes of tuna in cat food. duna is an appropriate term indeed.

Comment: Maybe the thing that needs to be fixed is your taste in music. Just sayin'

Answer (score 27):

Check out my Rhythmbox plugin, [rbpitch](http://launchpad.net/rbpitch) for changing the pitch/tempo/speed of the playing song. I know it's a hack, and you'll have to manually work out the correct tempo to set to get it to flash in sync with your cursor, but for this extremely important and practical task, I thought it would be important to give you a temporary workaround until someone figures out how to work a gstreamer pipeline using the beat detection plugin into `bash` or whatever virtual terminal you're using.

You know, now that you mention it, doing this wouldn't be all that extremely hard, and I could probably code it up in about a day using SoundTouch's BPMDetect class.

Stop giving me ideas for how to look busy coding while actually wasting time.

Comment: Dude,Im glad you acknoledge the importance of this question. I will try your workaround as a temporary messure but feel that the cursor should adjust to the tempo of the track. I dont care if it only matches for this one track as its the only track I own and I listen to it constantly on a loop.

Answer (score 10):

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'tput cnorm' EXIT
states=("$(tput civis)" "$(tput cnorm)")
state=0
while :; do
    printf %s "${states[state=!state]}"
    sleep .1
done
```

Music synchronization an exercise for reader.

Answer (score 0):

`Beat detection` is a task in the field of `Music information retrieval`. Usually vocals are stripped, the arrangement is classified in ~7 frequency buckets to create a [key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_%28music%29), the arrangement is discretised in those and local maxima are denoted as beat locations. The resulting sequence is smoothed to get a rythm  with constant frequency.

From there on your question is no longer an open research question but a purely technical one about `bash` or `vim` or `X` or whoever draws the cursor.

Simple.